# setOnMouseDragged not working on browser view

Tags: java, javafx, drag, jxbrowser

I'm writing a simple application in java using JxBrowser engine but i'm stuck at the very beginning. In my code, there is an undecorated `stage` that i want to make it draggable. To do so, searched and found the following link:

[How to drag undecorated window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173956/how-to-drag-undecorated-window)

So I set `mousePressed` and `MouseDragged` event on `stackPane` but only `mousePressed` event gets fired and `mouseDragged` event no way gets fired. Any idea of what's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

private static double xOffset = 0;
private static double yOffset = 0;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

        Browser browser = new Browser();

        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();

        pane.getChildren().add(browserView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 380, 500);

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                System.out.println("mouse pressed");

                xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();

                yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();

            }

        });

        pane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                System.out.println("mouse dragged");

                primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);

                primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);

            }

        });

        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Just a guess: Perhaps you should `primaryStage.show();` before you attach the event listeners.

Comment: unfortunately not helping :(

Comment: since jxbrowser requires a license I cant test it locally. My next guess would be to add the event listeners to the pane or even the browser itself.

Comment: Thanks man but no change. I can give you the license, it's a free one for open source project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jxbrowser requires license I couldn't test it... So I replaced that with Label and it works fine.. So my guess is that you are trying to drag by clicking on the browser itself and not the StackPane.. Try clicking at the corner of the Stage or else add stack pane to VBox and setPadding to it.. And try clicking at the corner.. If your clicking on the browser then browser's mouse events will be trigerred..

Proof:
[image]

**The correct code**

```
package RezRem;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class Main extends Application {

private static double xOffset = 0;
private static double yOffset = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);


    Browser browser = new Browser();

    BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    pane.getChildren().add(browserView);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 380, 500);

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            System.out.println("mouse pressed");

            xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();

            yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();

        }

    });

    pane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            System.out.println("mouse dragged");

            primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);

            primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);

        }

    });
    browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    primaryStage.show();

}

}
```

**Reason**

The jxbrowser extends till the edge so the stack pane wasn't on top neither was it visible on the sides so the mouse listener's never got triggered by setting the padding of stack pane there was 10px gap on all four sides where, if clicked, triggered the mouse events and thereby solves the problem..

Comment: "Try clicking at the corner of the Stage" didn't help. I created an instanse of VBox, `vb`, and set `padding` on it. Then I added `pane` to `vb` and created the `scene` this way : `Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 300, 500);`. Also added drag and mouse press listeners to `vb`. At the end, the listeners were working correctly ! but the browser didn't show anything even when I loaded an html.(Loading html works fine without VBox). Besides, I can give you the license if you think it can help. My license is a free one for open source project. Thanks for the try.

Comment: Wait for ten minutes or so.. I'll try a workaround.. So that you don't have to use vbox..

Comment: How are you loading the web page?

Comment: `browser.loadURL(Main.class.getResource("templates/login.html").toExternalForm());`, I have also tried something simple such as `browser.loadHTML("<html><head></head><body>Hello There</body></html>");` but none of them work.

Comment: `.loadURL` or `loadHTML` return value is `void`.

Comment: I meant when that statement executes what is the path you are going to get.. Put that in a system.out.println

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, output is not null, it's the absolute address of the file in my system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103834/discussion-between-vaibhav-g-and-mehran-torki).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. I ended up solving it by using the `setMouseEventsHandler` method on `BrowserView` which does seem to receive all the events you need (although it does not seem to receive `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED` events unless they have been rebranded as `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED` events).

```java
Rectangle[] dragIncludeRects = ...; // The area which is draggable (ie the title bar)
Rectangle[] dragExcludeRects = ...; // Exclusions (ie a close button on the title bar)
BrowserView popupView = ...;
JDialog popupFrame = ...; // could also be JFrame
Point dragOffset = null;
popupView.setMouseEventsHandler(new InputEventsHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  public boolean handle(MouseEvent event) {
    switch(event.getID()) {
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
        if (
          dragIncludeRects.exists((rect) => rect.contains(event.getPoint())) &&
          !dragExcludeRects.exists((rect) => rect.contains(event.getPoint()))
        ) {
          dragOffset = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(
              popupView, event.getPoint(), popupFrame);
        } else {
          dragOffset = null;
        }
        break;
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
        dragOffset = null;
        break;
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED:
        if (dragOffset != null) {
          // Note I tried using the position from the event but it doesn't work well
          val position = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
          popupFrame.setLocation(position.x - offset.x, position.y - offset.y);
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
})
```