# Custom titlebar drag behaviour does not support window snap

Tags: java, javafx

While this stackoverflow post helps solve the drag issue
[How to drag an undecorated window (stage) of JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173956/how-to-drag-an-undecorated-window-stage-of-javafx)

It definitly doesn't let window snap work, is there some way i'm supposed to use this to get window snap working?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Window snap", but I think it is a Microsoft Windows specific behavior. The behavior of the default title bar dragging is implemented by the underlying operating system; as soon as you give that implementation up by using an undecorated window, of course you lose any OS-specific behavior. The mouse dragging implementation will only implement what you write the code for it to do, so if you want "window snap" behavior, you would just have to code that yourself.

Comment: Oh, well, alright, but it seems like JetBrains IDEs are able to do it @James_D

Comment: My IntelliJ installation looks much more like a `UNIFIED` window, than an `UNDECORATED` one (though I am on a mac). I'm note sure that it's written in JavaFX, so the comparison may not be directly relevant anyway.

Comment: Oh, after looking through the source code, its written via SWING

Comment: do you want snap like when you drag  at the very left to the screen and the window resize height all the way up ?

Comment: Yep, window snapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a single Class javafx App you can try . You can drag the stage with the green circle and close App  with the red one .  when `stage.getX==0` is at the left of the screen and the app resize at `maxHeight` of the screen wich is in `Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY()` and `Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxX()` divided by two to get half width of the screen . for the right side is a litte bit tricky when `stage.getX()` pluss the current width of the window matchs `Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY()` means the right side of the window reaches the right side of the screen , but when the app is rezised in the right its x coordinate change , that will trigger the listener again , to avoid that I put a boolean `boolean isInRightSide` . You can comment and uncomment that boolean to see that behavior . Any other values of x position of the stage will reset to the original sizes .

```
public class App extends Application {

boolean isInRightSide = false;
double offsetX;
double offsetY;
int defaultWidth = 640;
int defaultHeight = 480;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    double screenMaxX = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth();
    System.out.println(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds());

    Circle dragCircle = new Circle(30, new Color(0, 1, 0, 1));
    Circle closeCircle = new Circle(30, new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));
    HBox hBox = new HBox(dragCircle, closeCircle);
    closeCircle.setOnMouseClicked(e -> stage.close());

    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_RIGHT);

    dragCircle.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

        
            offsetX = e.getSceneX();
            offsetY = e.getSceneY();
        

    }
    );

    dragCircle.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {

        stage.setX(e.getScreenX() - offsetX);
        stage.setY(e.getScreenY() - offsetY);
        e.consume();
    });

    // sanap to left  and right 
    stage.xProperty().addListener(e -> {

        if (stage.getX() + defaultWidth > screenMaxX) {
            stage.setX(screenMaxX - defaultWidth);

        }

        if (stage.getX() <= 0 && !stage.isFullScreen()) {
            stage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY());
            stage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxX() / 2);

        } else if (!isInRightSide) {
            stage.setHeight(defaultHeight);
            stage.setWidth(defaultWidth);
        }
        if (stage.getX() + defaultWidth == screenMaxX) {
            isInRightSide = true;

            stage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxY());
            stage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getMaxX() / 2);

        } else {
            isInRightSide = false;
        }

    });

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane(hBox), defaultWidth, defaultHeight);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
```

app start
[image: app start]

app snap when reaches right side

[image: undecorated javafx snap]