# Move undecorated stage on mouse drag

Tags: java, javafx

I set the style of stage as

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

But now I want to able to move the stage window. How to do that?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22960073. the part "drag to move".

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `root` is your parent node, the one that you use while creating `Scene`. `xOffset` and `yOffset` are `double` type variables. You can achieve dragging the window using the following code:

```
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            xOffset = event.getSceneX();
            yOffset = event.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check out this SO post for the example usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13460743/5250273

Comment: i understand to use. During use from code cursor Mouse Top left!! help me

Answer (score 0):

**i understand**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application
 {

private double xOffset = 0;
private double yOffset = 0;
private static class Delta {
    double x, y;
}

final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
final BooleanProperty inDrag = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

@Override  public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            dragDelta.x = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
            xOffset = event.getSceneX();
            yOffset = event.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
            primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
            primaryStage.getWidth();
            primaryStage.getHeight();
            primaryStage.getX();
            primaryStage.getY();
            inDrag.set(true);

        }
    });
    primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}
```

}