# JavaFX - Add Event Handler To Stage's Title Bar

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, addeventlistener, stage

I am trying to add event handler to the stage's title bar, but it won't work.

I tried using this:

```
primaryStage.addEVentHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (event)->{
     System.out.println("ok");
});
```

But it only register the event to the scene's area and won't read the mouse pressed event on the title bar.

Is there a way to listen the mouse event on stage's title bar?

**Complete code:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox box = new HBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 350, 250);

        Text text = new Text("Test");
        box.getChildren().add(text);

        primaryStage.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,(event) -> {
            System.out.println("ok");
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TimePicker");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible, as the user expects a certain behaviour from interaction with the titlebar as determined by the underlying OS. If you start handling mouse events on the titlebar, you would likley interfere with this expected behaviour.

This said, by hiding the titlebar by setting `primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);` it would be possible to implement your own title bar, that provides your custom behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to do anything with the system default title bar. It's not a node and it doesn't respond in a negative coordinate space.

Possible workaround: Create your own title bar!

Make your primary stage and style it as StageStyle.UNDECORATED.

Use a root pane like BorderPane to develop your own title bar at the top.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206193/how-to-make-an-undecorated-window-movable-draggable-in-javafx) for making an UNDECORATED stage draggable (basically dragging the top of your BorderPane).

Good luck!

Comment: then what combobox do to hide the popup?

Comment: I'm sorry, what pop-up?

Comment: the area that contain emails like what is shown in this picture http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/img/combobox-simple.png

Comment: This seems like a whole new question. Please make a new post of you have questions relating to ComboBox or node layouts.